# How to create an Instance of an Object in StructureMap Dynamically?

Tags: c#, abstract-class, structuremap

I have an Abstract Class called "ImportRunner".

I have an implementation of the class called "ScorecardRunner".

How can I at runtime get an instance of a class such as ScorecardRunner, when I am pulling the Object Type back as a String from an XML File and it could be any implementation of ImportRunner?

My current code is as follows.

```
var importer = container.GetInstance<ImportRunner>();
```

When I try to do something like below I get a compile error.

```
var importer = container.GetInstance<Type.GetType("Importer.ScorecardRunner")>();
```

> Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and
>   'Type'

Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of spreading your logic for creating an instance based on runtime values and shoehorning it into your StructureMap's registry, a better approach would be to simply create a factory that's responsible for determining the correct runner instance and inject that.

For example:

```
public class XmlReader
{
    public bool IsScoreCard { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ImportRunner
{
}

public class ScorecardRunner : ImportRunner
{
}

public class DefaultRunner : ImportRunner
{
}

public class RunnerFactory
{
    private readonly XmlReader _reader;

    public RunnerFactory(XmlReader reader)
    {
        _reader = reader;
    }

    public ImportRunner Resolve()
    {
        if (_reader.IsScoreCard)
            return new ScorecardRunner();

        return new DefaultRunner();
    }
}
```

Then configure it like so in your registry:

```
this.For<ImportRunner>().Use(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<RunnerFactory>().Resolve());
```

Comment: Really `For<RunnerFactory>`? Smells like a type mismatch.

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry, but I disagree with the answers general assertion.

You shouldn't need to create concrete factories if you are using IoC...that is the whole point of dependency injection.

Consider this small example...

- The UnitOfWork will be instantiated by StructureMap
- The BankAccountApplication can & should also be instantiated by StructureMap

**Process.BankAccounts Library  - Sample Class:** 
Notice how the UnitOfWork class is referenced by the Application classes property.

```
public class BankAccountApplication : IAccountApplication
{
    #region <Fields & Constants>

    private string StartingBalanceInvalidFormat = "A Starting Balance of {0} is invalid.";
    private string AnnualPercentageRateInvalidFormat = "The Annual Percentage Rate of {0} is invalid.";

    #endregion

    #region <Properties>

    [SetterProperty]
    public IDemoDbUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region <Methods>

    public BankAccount CreateNew(AccountType bankAccountType, string ownerFullName, decimal startingBalance, decimal annualPercentageRate, string executedBy)
    {
        TraceHandler.TraceIn(TraceLevel.Info);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ownerFullName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Owner Full Name");

        if (startingBalance < 0.0M)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(StartingBalanceInvalidFormat, startingBalance));

        if (annualPercentageRate <= 0.0M)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(AnnualPercentageRateInvalidFormat, annualPercentageRate));

        var account = new BankAccount();

        try
        {
            BankAccountType accountType = GetAccountType(bankAccountType);

            account.AnnualPercentageRate = annualPercentageRate;
            account.Balance = startingBalance;
            account.BankAccountTypeId = accountType.BankAccountTypeId;
            account.OwnerFullName = ownerFullName;
            account.ExecutedByName = executedBy;
            account.ExecutedDatetime = DateTime.UtcNow;

            UnitOfWork.BankAccounts.Add(account);
            UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TraceHandler.TraceError(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            TraceHandler.TraceOut();
        }

        return account;
    }

    public IEnumerable<BankAccount> FindOverdrafts(IAccountAlgorithm overdraftAlgorithm)
    {
        TraceHandler.TraceIn(TraceLevel.Info);

        var accounts = new List<BankAccount>();

        try
        {
            var entities = UnitOfWork.BankAccounts.GetAll().ToList();

            entities.ForEach(e => {

                IAlgorithmResult calculation = overdraftAlgorithm.Calculate(e.Balance);

                if (calculation.Result)
                    accounts.Add(e);
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TraceHandler.TraceError(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            TraceHandler.TraceOut();
        }

        return accounts.AsEnumerable();
    }

    private BankAccountType GetAccountType(AccountType bankAccountType)
    {
        var name = bankAccountType.ToStringValue();

        // In this case I am going to assume all accounts are properly mapped -> First()
        return UnitOfWork.BankAccountTypes.GetAll().Where(a => a.BankAccountTypeName == name).First();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Process.BankAccounts Library - ContainerRegistry :** 
This ContainerRegistry scans the assemblies & "sets-up" your root interfaces, and then, uses your commands for more "explicit" instructions.

```
public class ContainerRegistry : Registry
{
    #region <Constructors>

    public ContainerRegistry()
    {
        Scan(
            scan =>
            {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                scan.LookForRegistries();
                scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(f => f.FullName.StartsWith("Bushido.Common", true, null));
                scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(f => f.FullName.StartsWith("Bushido.Process", true, null));
                scan.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IAccountApplication));
                scan.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IAccountAlgorithm));
                scan.SingleImplementationsOfInterface();
            });

        ForSingletonOf(typeof(IDbContext)).Use(typeof(DemoDbContext));

        For(typeof(IDemoDbUnitOfWork)).Use(typeof(DemoDbUnitOfWork));
        For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(GenericRepository<>));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**UnitTest Library - Builder:** 
Of course, in a Unit Test, you must Mock 3rd party objects.  But you can & should use IoC to do it.

```
    public partial class Builder
    {
        #region <Methods>

        public T CreateInstance<T>(IDemoDbUnitOfWork unitOfWork, bool byFullName = false)
        {
            if (unitOfWork == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("UnitOfWork");

            // Here, I am passing-in a MOCK of the UnitOfWork & "shimming" it into "T" via IoC
            var container = IoC.Initialize();
            container.Inject(typeof(IDemoDbUnitOfWork), unitOfWork);

            return container.GetInstance<T>();
        }

        public Mock<IDemoDbUnitOfWork> CreateMockUnitOfWork()
        {
            var unitOfWork = new Mock<IDemoDbUnitOfWork>();

            // DBO Tables
            var bankAccountRepository = BankAccountRepositoryBuilder.CreateMock();
            var bankAccountTypeRepository = BankAccountTypeRepositoryBuilder.CreateMock();

            unitOfWork.SetupAllProperties();

            // DBO Tables
            unitOfWork.SetupGet(x => x.BankAccounts).Returns(bankAccountRepository.Object);
            unitOfWork.SetupGet(x => x.BankAccountTypes).Returns(bankAccountTypeRepository.Object);

            return unitOfWork;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

**UnitTest Library - Tests:** 
Now, through the Builder class, you can instantiate your classes...and by consequence, you're Unit Tests clean-up nicely.

```
public void BankAccountApplication_CreateNew_Invalid_StartingBalance()
{
     // -----
     // ARRANGE

     var unitOfWork = Builder.CreateMockUnitOfWork();
     var application = Builder.CreateInstance<BankAccountApplication>(unitOfWork);

     // -----
     // ACT
     var account = application.CreateNew(AccountType.Checking, "Scrooge McDuck", -100.00M, 3.00M, Builder.ExecutedBy);

     // -----
     // ASSERT

     ...put your asserts here
}
```